# Getting TypeError as registerHelper is not a function when using handlebars in node js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars, registerhelper

My node js application is having the below code wherein I am trying to register a handlebars if-else logic in order to use that in my template file. However it is throwing error as "TypeError: hbs.registerHelper is not a function". Can anybody point me the mistakes I am making and suggest how can I register a if - elseif -else logic to carry out an equality (or comparison) check to construct the decision making logic in my template ?

The express-handlebars version in package.json is 3.0.0

```
var exp = require('express');
var pth = require('path');
var fcon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cp = require('cookie-parser');
var bp = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

exphbs.registerHelper("if", function(conditional, options) {
  if (options.hash.desired === options.hash.type) {
    options.fn(this);
  } else {
    options.inverse(this);
  }
});

// view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/mylayouts/'}));
app.set('views', pth.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers can only be registered for instance of express-handlebars:

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
    helpers: {
        foo: function () { return 'FOO!'; },
        bar: function () { return 'BAR!'; }
    }
});
```

Or if you want to register them dynamic. You can use instance reference like this:

```
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper("superHelper", () => 42);
```

Moving further you may want to override helper at the render level. You can do it like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {
        showTitle: true,

        // Override `foo` helper only for this rendering.
        helpers: {
            foo: function () { return 'foo.'; }
        }
    });
});
```

Source: [projects github page](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)

Edit:

Adding `if` helper:

```
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
  extname: 'hbs', 
  defaultLayout: 'layout', 
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/mylayouts/',
  helpers: {
    if: function(conditional, options) {
      if (options.hash.desired === options.hash.type) {
        options.fn(this);
      } else {
        options.inverse(this);
      }
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I use the above syntax to my requirement of an if-elseif-else logic ? One example syntax would be helpful.

Comment: the answer helped. However one last question regarding the handlebars template. If I am send a variable 'p' which has a name attribute , then with that above logic in the if function this syntax would work ? {{#if p.name === "hello"}} , or I need to change the helper for that or need to write another helper to handle this ?

Comment: At first: `if` helper shuld be built in. To compare you need another helper - take a look on this project you can use or search for examples: https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers . There is a comparison section

Comment: Built in if helper? How can it be ? The express-handlebars I am using doesn't have built-in if helper. And if I write another helper for comparison then what is the use of the if helper function body which defined its behavior for comparison?

Comment: Idk what version do you use, but mine express-handlebars 3.0.0 have built in `if`. To find out standard block helper behaviour take a look at http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Comment: My express-handlebars version too is 3.0.0 as mentioned earlier. However is there a way to check what all helpers are available as built in ?

Comment: `console.log(hbs.handlebars.helpers)`.  
`{ blockHelperMissing: [Function],
  each: [Function],
  helperMissing: [Function],
  if: [Function],
  unless: [Function],
  log: [Function],
  lookup: [Function],
  with: [Function] }`